# If I rename the keys of a set of data on S3 will the data be repartitioned?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have store 50GB of data in S3 in a structure like this
bucket----
          /1
          /2
          /3
          /4
etc...

and I have read that this is a bad practice on storing data in S3. The good practice is using hash in front of the key so the data will be stored in different places.
(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html )

Now if I rename the keys, will the data be repartitioned, or I need to create a new bucket and then move the data ?

Comment: Wait a minute.  Are you trying to fix a problem, or are you trying to be proactive? It doesn't need to be a "hash" -- it just needs to be something that doesn't increment lexically in a way that creates hot spots. Additonally, these guidelines do not need to be followed at all if you are creating fewer than 100 objects per second.  What you have, now, may be perfectly fine.  If your bucket and objects are already there, you shouldn't need to change it.  Explain what you mean by /1 /2 /3 /4.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the bucket structure is like that:
bucket/1,
bucket/2,
bucket/3, etc...
bucket/1000000000

So if I want to read these files, it would take days.

Comment: Ah, dual motivation, then.  Note that "renaming," as is pointed out in the answer, is really copy+delete, and you will lose your existing objects' `Last-Modified` (creation) date -- the `Last-Modified` value will be set to `now()` on the copies.  You'll want to take steps to preserve it, by copying it into x-amz-meta user metadata, if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will be repartitioned, because when you rename a file in S3 you are really copying it to a new file with the new name and the old one gets deleted - so it will behave as if you had given it the new name to begin with.